# Is it almost impossible for the values of continuous random variables to lie on a plane?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a random variable with density $f$ (the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is absolutely continuous). Let $x_1, \dots, x_{d}$ be the set of values of $d$ i.i.d. copies of $X$. Do we have that $$\mathbb{P} \left( x_1, \dots, x_{d} \text{ are coplanar} \right)=0,$$
where "plane" is read as $a+U$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $U$ a $k \leq d-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$? Moreover, could we more generally say that
$$\mathbb{P} \left( x_1, \dots, x_{d} \in M\right)=0,$$
where $M$ is any smooth manifold uniquely defined by $d-1$ points (a lower dimensional sphere, say).

This seems super obvious, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I would like to write something like "Consider $x_1, \dots,x_{d-1} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. We would now need $x_d \in M$, with $M$ specified by $x_1, \dots, x_{d-1}$. Since $M$ is of measure zero (Hausdorff dimension $< d$) and $X$ is absolutely continuous $\mathbb{P}(x_d \in M ) = 0$".

Now, for me, the problem with the above thing is that we are implicitly conditioning on a zero probability event ($M$ being a specific manifold). You can't simply partition $\Omega$ to $A_M$ by events $A_M = "\text{the manifold specified by the first observations is } M$ and write
$$\mathbb{P} \left( x_1, \dots, x_{d} \in M \right) = \sum \limits_{M^* \in \mathcal{M}} \mathbb{P} \left( x_1, \dots, x_{d} \in M \middle| M= M^* \right) = 0.$$
I'm pretty sure there is a well known way to deal with these zero-probability events rigorously or avoid dealing with them directly alltogether.

Comment: You have some confusion with $d$ and $d+1$, which should be $d$ on all occasions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @zhoraster. I was switching back and forth and forgot to change some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will use capital letters for random variables and small letters for non-random numbers.)

Your argument is correct, it just needs to be written properly.

A useful fact: if $X, Y$ are independent, then 
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(X,Y)] = \mathsf{E}[E[f(x,Y)]|_{x=X}].
$$
In particular,
$$
\mathsf{P}\big((X,Y)\in A\big) = \mathsf{E}[P\big((x,Y)\in A\big)|_{x=X}].
$$

So it is in fact enough that $X_d$ is independent of $X_1,\dots,X_{d-1}$ and has a density. Indeed,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_1,\dots,X_d \text{ coplanar}) = \mathsf{E}\big(\mathsf{P}(x_1,\dots,x_{d-1},X_d \text{ coplanar})|_{x_1 = X_1,\dots, x_{d-1} = X_{d-1}}\big) = 0,
$$
since the inner probability is zero for any $x_1,\dots,x_{d-1}$.